# Get XSD schema for C# type

Tags: c#, xsd

how can I generate a xsd schema for a c# type (in code). There must be certainly a way, because xsd schema is generated for datacontracts in wcf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found a solution to my problem by looking with reflector in the xsd.exe. Here is it for future reference:

```
XmlReflectionImporter importer = new XmlReflectionImporter();
XmlTypeMapping stringMapping = importer.ImportTypeMapping(typeof(String));
```

Answer (score 2):

Going a bit farther than s7orm's answer I wrote this simple function that I derived from reflecting on xsd.exe:

```
private void ExtractXsdFromType(Type type, FileInfo xsd)
    {
        XmlReflectionImporter importer = new XmlReflectionImporter();
        XmlTypeMapping mapping = importer.ImportTypeMapping(type);
        XmlSchemas xmlSchemas = new XmlSchemas();
        XmlSchemaExporter xmlSchemaExporter = new XmlSchemaExporter(xmlSchemas);            

        using (FileStream fs = xsd.Create())
        {
            xmlSchemaExporter.ExportTypeMapping(mapping);
            xmlSchemas[0].Write(fs);
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [XML Schema Definition Tool (xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx)

```
xsd.exe YourAssembly.dll /type:YourNamespace.YourType
```

Comment: Yeah I know, but I want to generate the schema in code, not via tool.